# 実機テストで「未検証」が「検証済み」にならない問題

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode7

失礼します。
本日Xcodeの7.0をインストールし、利用しています。

実機テストが無料で可能とのことでApple IDを登録して実際にHelloWorldをBuildしてみました。
(実機にはプロファイルから自分のApple IDをあらかじめ信頼させてあります。)

するとXcodeでは

```
Could not launch “Hello World”
process launch failed: Security
```

と表示されました。
iPhoneのプロファイルの画面では、

```
HelloWorld　　　未検証
```

となっており、何度「Appを検証」ボタンを押しても検証されません。

この前にXcode7.1のbeta3で検証したのですが、その際はうまくいきました。なぜXcode7.0ではこのようなエラーが出るのでしょうか？

同じようなエラーが出る方、いらっしゃいますでしょうか。
また、解決方法をご存知の方いらっしゃいましたら、ご教授お願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

iPhone/iPadの実機をMacに接続したとき、「このコンピュータを信頼するか」というアラートが出たと思います。このとき「信頼する」を選択したにもかかわらず、信頼になっていないようです。つまりXcode 7.0.xにバグがあるんじゃないかという印象があります。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

このダイアログが出たら、実機の「設定」＞「一般」を開きます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

「プロファイル」をタップして、「デベロッパAPP」を「信頼する」にします。
この項目「プロファイル」は、実機を、Xcodeが起動しているMacに接続しないと現れません。
私の場合は、これでプロジェクトを実機に転送することができました。